# How can I combine two arrays by key and value?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array "products":

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "78f895684c"
    "Name" => "test1"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "f71db561ba"
    "Name" => "Zwei"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "3e231651de"
    "Name" => "Test3"
  ]
]
```

This is my array "category":

```
array:3 [▼
  "78f895684c" => "pink"
  "f71db561ba" => "blue"
  "3e231651de" => "pink"
]
```

I try to create a new array, that sort my products into the category.
This is my approach:

```
 foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
   $test = $category[$value["uuid"]];
   $new[$test] = array();
   array_push($new,$value);
 }
```

The result I expect is:

```
array:5 [▼
  "blue" => 
     [0] => array:2 [▼
      "uuid" => "f71db561ba"
      "Name" => "Zwei"
  ]
  "pink" => 
    [1] => array:2 [▼
       "uuid" => "78f895684c"
       "Name" => "test1"
    [2] => array:2 [▼
    "uuid" => "3e231651de"
    "Name" => "Test3"
  ]
]
```

But my result is:

```
array:5 [▼
  "pink" => []
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "78f895684c"
    "Name" => "test1"
  ]
  "blue" => []
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "f71db561ba"
    "Name" => "Zwei"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "uuid" => "3e231651de"
    "Name" => "Test3"
  ]
]
```

Comment: instead `$new[$test] = array();
   array_push($new,$value);` use `$new[$test][]= $value;`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this: `$new[$cat][] = $value;`

Example:

```
$new = array();

foreach ($products as $prod) {
  $cat = $category[$prod['uuid']];

  $new[$cat][] = $prod;
}
```

Working demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/FlawlessTerribleOutcome)

Answer (score 1):

you are pushing the element into the wrong array with

```
array_push($new,$value);
```

because you need to insert it into `$new[$test]` so instead do

```
array_push($new[$test],$value);
```

Also check if the `$new[$test]` already exists, otherwise create the array:

```
if(!$new[$test]) $new[$test] = array();
```

So at the end the code is

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
   $test = $category[$value["uuid"]];
   if(!$new[$test]) $new[$test] = array();
   array_push($new[$test],$value);
}
```